# Having some errors, learning c (Euclidean Algorithm)

Tags: c

So I have done some programming in Python before, and trying my hands out with some old solutions/methods I used from there. But I am having some syntax/compiler errors and I feel like Im missing something. Probably something really dumb but here is the code.

```
//Euclidian Algorithm In C
//a=bq+r gcd(a,b)=gcd(b,r)
//Recursive Solution
//Devin Martin

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS    // to avoid scanf warning or error
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b = 0;
    int gcd(a, b); 
    {
        if (b == 0);
            return a;
        return gcd(b, a % b);  //a%b = r
    }
}
```

Errors
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _gcd referenced in function _main    EuclidianAlgorithm  D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\EuclidianAlgorithm\EuclidianAlg.obj    1

Warning C4700   uninitialized local variable 'a' used   EuclidianAlgorithm  d:\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\euclidianalgorithm\euclidianalg.c  14

Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  EuclidianAlgorithm  D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\EuclidianAlgorithm\Debug\EuclidianAlgorithm.exe    1

Comment: It seems that this is not the only file you have. Do you have any other files in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define a function inside of another function in C.  Also, the function definition is incorrect, as you need to declare the type of the parameters inside of the parameter list.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);  //a%b = r
}

int main()
{
    printf("gcd(15,6)=%d\n",gcd(15,6));
}
```